# kubernete cluster running on kind , setting up prometheus and grafana for monitoring

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, kind

I have installed prometheus in namespace monitoring and grafana in default namespace.
can i copy or move any of this in either default namespace or monitoring namespace.
What can be the possible issues i can face going forward ?

I tried this : helm install grafana grafana/grafana (installed in default namespace)

i want to move this to namespace monitoring so i tried this :
helm install grafana grafana/grafana --namespace monitoring

but get this error :
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: ClusterRole "grafana-clusterrole" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" must equal "monitoring": current value is "default"

Answer (score 0):

Kindly remove helm using helm uninstall from default namespace and then install again in specified namespace by using -n (namespace)
e.g helm install grafana grafana/grafana -n monitoring

this will work